# How to use google map with advanced markers in react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, babeljs

I was trying to create a custom marker using [Google Maps advanced markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/html-markers)

Data so that you can reproduce the example. Just put any image where image is being used.

```
 const center = {
    lat: 28.7041,
    lng: 77.102,
  };

  const markers = [
    {
      key: "1",
      coordinates: {
        lat: 28.7041,
        lng: 77.102,
      },
      marker: {
        text: "BUS-001",
        backgroundColor: "black",
      },
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      coordinates: {
        lat: 28.4557,
        lng: 77.032,
      },
      marker: {
        text: "BUS-002",
        backgroundColor: "red",
      },
    },
    {
      key: "3",
      coordinates: {
        lat: 28.457,
        lng: 77.0412,
      },
      marker: {
        text: "BUS-003",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
      },
    },
  ];
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"; // Update the import statement
import busTopViewImage from "../assets/bus-top-view.png";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";


const Map = ({ center, markers }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function initMap() {
      const { Map } = (await google.maps.importLibrary(
        "maps"
      )) as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
      const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = (await google.maps.importLibrary(
        "marker"
      )) as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;

      const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map-view") as HTMLElement, {
        center,
        zoom: 14,
        mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
      });
      let mapMarkers = [];
      for (let markerData of markers) {
        const markerComponent = document.createElement("div");
        markerComponent.innerHTML = `
  <img src="${busTopViewImage}" />
  <h5 style="background-color: ${markerData.marker.backgroundColor}; color: white; border-radius: 10px; padding: 8px;">
        ${markerData.marker.text}
  </h5>
`;
        const m = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map,
          position: markerData.coordinates,
          content: markerComponent,
        });
        mapMarkers.push(m);
      }
    }
    initMap();
  }, []);

  return <div id="map-view" style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}></div>;
};
export default Map;
```

The issue I am facing is that I want to use a React component as marker as below.

```
const Marker = ({ text, backgroundColor }) => {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      justifyContent="stretch"
      alignItems="center"
      direction="column"
      style={{
        boxShadow: "0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
        marginBottom: "3rem",
      }}
    >
      <img src={busTopViewImage} alt="Bus Marker" />
      <Grid
        item
        style={{
          boxShadow: "0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          borderRadius: "10px",
          padding: "0 0.5rem",
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="body1" color="white">
          {text}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

To what I know about react, it uses babel to convert jsx to javascript nodes using the `document.createElement` as that api wants. I want to know if there is any library/react function that can ingest this `Marker` component and help me use remove that ugly `markerComponent.innerHTML` in that useEffect.
If you know of any method please share an example or provide some sources of information.

I already tried the react packages available for google maps. Some only allow static images and one of them accepted the Marker but while zooming in and out didn't change the marker position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell, you can pass DOM nodes into advanced markers like you have here:

```
        const markerComponent = document.createElement("div");
        markerComponent.innerHTML = `
  <img src="${busTopViewImage}" />
  <h5 style="background-color: ${markerData.marker.backgroundColor}; color: white; border-radius: 10px; padding: 8px;">
        ${markerData.marker.text}
  </h5>
`;
        const m = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map,
          position: markerData.coordinates,
          content: markerComponent,
        });
```

The only thing you're missing is to generate the HTML via React.

```
    // Setup a React root on a virtual DOM node
    const markerComponent = document.createElement("div");
    // Initialize root at new DOM node
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el);
    // Output HTML into it
    root.render(<Marker ... />);

     // Use it
    const m = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map,
          position: markerData.coordinates,
          content: markerComponent,
        });
```

If you need to share state with the rest of the tree, you can combine this with [Portals](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this youtube video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxYqoY2WwE

Github source code: https://github.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-threejs/blob/main/pages/markers.js

```
import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper
      apiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_API_KEY}
      version="beta"
      libraries={["marker"]}
    >
      <MyMap />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const mapOptions = {
  mapId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_ID,
  center: { lat: 43.66293, lng: -79.39314 },
  zoom: 10,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
};

function MyMap() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, mapOptions));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} id="map" />
      {map && <Weather map={map} />}
    </>
  );
}

const weatherData = {
  A: {
    name: "Toronto",
    position: { lat: 43.66293, lng: -79.39314 },
    climate: "Raining",
    temp: 20,
    fiveDay: [15, 18, 12, 22, 20],
  },
  B: {
    name: "Guelph",
    position: { lat: 43.544811, lng: -80.248108 },
    climate: "Cloudy",
    temp: 20,
    fiveDay: [15, 18, 12, 22, 20],
  },
  C: {
    name: "Orangeville",
    position: { lat: 43.919239, lng: -80.097412 },
    climate: "Sunny",
    temp: 20,
    fiveDay: [15, 18, 12, 22, 20],
  },
};

function Weather({ map }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(weatherData);
  const [highlight, setHighlight] = useState();
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      {editing && (
        <Editing
          weather={data[editing]}
          update={(newWeather) => {
            setData((existing) => {
              return { ...existing, [editing]: { ...newWeather } };
            });
          }}
          close={() => setEditing(null)}
        />
      )}
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, weather]) => (
        <Marker
          key={key}
          map={map}
          position={weather.position}
          onClick={() => setEditing(key)}
        >
          <div
            className={`marker ${weather.climate.toLowerCase()} ${
              highlight === key || editing === key ? "highlight" : ""
            }`}
            onMouseEnter={() => setHighlight(key)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHighlight(null)}
          >
            <h2>{weather.climate}</h2>
            <div>{weather.temp}c</div>
            {highlight === key || editing === key ? (
              <div className="five-day">
                <p>Next 5</p>
                <p>{weather.fiveDay.join(", ")}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function Editing({ weather, update, close }) {
  return (
    <div className="editing">
      <h2>Editing {weather.name}</h2>

      <label htmlFor="climate">Climate</label>
      <select
        id="climate"
        value={weather.climate}
        onChange={(e) => update({ ...weather, climate: e.target.value })}
      >
        {["Sunny", "Cloudy", "Raining"].map((val) => (
          <option key={val} value={val}>
            {val}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <label htmlFor="temp">Temperature</label>
      <input
        id="temp"
        type="number"
        value={weather.temp}
        onChange={(e) => update({ ...weather, temp: e.target.value })}
      />

      <button type="button" onClick={() => close()}>
        Close
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Marker({ map, position, children, onClick }) {
  const rootRef = useRef();
  const markerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rootRef.current) {
      const container = document.createElement("div");
      rootRef.current = createRoot(container);

      markerRef.current = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
        position,
        content: container,
      });
    }

    return () => (markerRef.current.map = null);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    rootRef.current.render(children);
    markerRef.current.position = position;
    markerRef.current.map = map;
    const listener = markerRef.current.addListener("click", onClick);
    return () => listener.remove();
  }, [map, position, children, onClick]);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35370538)

Answer (score 0):

There is a more straight forward and react friendly approach using `@googlemaps/react-wrapper` and `useRef`:

Map component:

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper"

import GoogleMapAdvancedMarker from "./components/GoogleMapAdvancedMarker"

const GoogleMap = (): ReactElement => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map>()
  const [isMakerLibraryLoaded, setIsMarkerLibraryLoaded] = useState(false)

  const isInitialized = isMakerLibraryLoaded

  useEffect(() => {
    window.google.maps
      .importLibrary("marker")
      .then(() => setIsMarkerLibraryLoaded(true))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current !== null && map === undefined && isInitialized) {
      setMap(
        new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
          mapId: import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_MAP_ID,
          clickableIcons: false,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          center: {
            lat: 48.85717983617828,
            lng: 2.3412462391153666,
          },
          zoom: 12,
        }),
      )
    }
  }, [map, isInitialized])

  return (
    <Wrapper apiKey={import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY}>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        {isInitialized && (
          <GoogleMapAdvancedMarker
            latitude={48.85717983617828}
            longitude={2.3412462391153666}
            map={map}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default GoogleMap
```

Marker component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export type AdvancedMarkerProps = Pick<
  google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement,
  "map"
> &
  Pick<GeolocationCoordinates, "latitude" | "longitude">

const GoogleMapAdvancedMaker = ({
  map,
  latitude,
  longitude,
}: AdvancedMarkerProps) => {
  const [marker, setMarker] =
    useState<google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (marker === undefined && map !== undefined) {
      setMarker(
        new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map,
          position: {
            lat: latitude,
            lng: longitude,
          },
        }),
      )
    }
  }, [latitude, longitude, map, marker])

  return null
}

export default GoogleMapAdvancedMaker
```